# Static objects randomly becoming null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, scope, nullpointerexception

I'm working on an application that uses the appsettings.json file to keep up with certain values, including the jwt secret key. Then I use dependency injection to fill up a static class, so that I can access these values from anywhere, including libraries. However, after the application is running for a certain amount of time (not exactly sure what, since it's anywhere from 30 minutes to several hours), the values in that static class are set to null, and the application throws an null exception. Is there something I'm missing from this? Why would this be happening? Code below.

```
   public JsonResult GenerateToken([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("LoginController-GenerateToken(): The contents of the config file are  {0}, {1}, {2}", AuthConfigurations.SecretKey, APIConfigurations.CustomerOneConnectionString, JwtConfigurations.JwtSecretKey);
        if (model != null)
        {
            bool result = LongIn(model); //returns true if login was successful

            if (result)
            {

                var claims = new[]
                {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, model.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtConfigurations.JwtSecretKey));
                var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(JwtConfigurations.Issuer, JwtConfigurations.Audience, claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(JwtConfigurations.TokenExpire), signingCredentials: creds);

                return Json(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(null);
            }
        }
        return Json(null);

    }
```

In here, sometimes, this call throws an exception because the JwtConfigurations static attributes (Issuer, Audience, JwtSecretKey) are null. I've been using the logger to log this.

Here's the static class and the service class

```
public class ConfigurationSettings
{
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public int TokenExpire { get; set; }
    public string JwtSecretKey { get; set; }

}


public static class JwtConfigurations
{
    public static string JwtSecretKey;
    public static string Audience;
    public static string Issuer;
    public static int TokenExpire; //In Seconds
}
```

and

```
public class ConfigureHandler : IConfigure
{
    private readonly IOptions<ConfigurationSettings> _settings;

    public ConfigureHandler(IOptions<ConfigurationSettings> settings, ILogger<ConfigureHandler> logger)
    {
        _settings = settings;

        JwtConfigurations.JwtSecretKey = _settings.Value.JwtSecretKey;
        JwtConfigurations.Audience = _settings.Value.Audience;
        JwtConfigurations.Issuer = _settings.Value.Issuer;
        JwtConfigurations.TokenExpire = _settings.Value.TokenExpire;
    }
}
```

And finally, where I add the service in the startup file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 .....
 services.AddSingleton<IConfigure, ConfigureHandler>();
}
```

Comment: So from a certain point all calls throw the exception? Or are there incidental exceptions?

Comment: This is the login call. So, basically, if I can't get past this, I can't get to the other calls. However, I do have a middleware layer, and it uses one of the values, and it also has the same issue.

Comment: And if you retry some time later the values remain null?

Comment: What is the value set to TokenExpire?

Comment: 3600. It's an integer value, but I haven't put it in the log statements, so I'm not sure what the value of it could be at the time this fails. But as for Ruad, no. Actually, if I retry several times, the value do not stay null.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with setting up the services in the thread. The singleton exists, but is somehow not passed into the thread. I have no idea how this all works, perhaps that others can tell if this scenario is even possible. But it seems to me that while initiating one of the non-singleton classes something happens that causes the setup of the services to abort. I don't know, perhaps it takes too long, an uncaught exception, a time-out, and since it happens after some time: somewhere a memory leak. Take a closer look at memory usage and the injected services and objects.

Comment: We're in 2018, don't use static classes to store this stuff. It's an anti-pattern for decades now ;) If you use dependency injection, use it **all the way**, also to inject JwtConfigurations as an **instanced** class, rather than **static**. Also **WHEN** is your `ConfigureHandler` resolved? When you never resolve it, it never sets the values. Just calling `services.AddSingleton<IConfigure, ConfigureHandler>();` create an instance of your `ConfigureHandler`

Comment: @user2850818 Did you resolve this?

Comment: I did. I just got rid of the static class and used the IOptions directly. It seems there is a problem where the static values will randomly change, and this doesn't occur when stop using the static class.

Comment: I did run into something similar. This was due to middleware, so that's why I asked. I found this explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#per-request-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static classes for configuration shouldn't be used in 2018, its an anti-pattern, causes hard-to-test classes and you never know if some thread changes it to something invalid in the mid of the execution.

When using Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control containers, you should always use it all the way down to your application and not mix anti-patterns (like static options).

You already know how to use `IOptions<T>` why don't you inject that into your controller?!?

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private ConfigurationSettings Config { get; }

    public LoginController(IOption<ConfigurationSettings> jwtOptions, ... /* other deps */)
    {
        Config = jwtOptions.Value;
    }

    public JsonResult GenerateToken([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        ...
        // this access the options injected in constructor
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(Config.Issuer, Config.Audience, claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Config.TokenExpire), signingCredentials: creds);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can just remove `ConfigureHandler` and `JwtConfigurations` from your code completely.

The real issue in your case seems, that you never resolve `ConfigureHandler`. Just calling

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigure, ConfigureHandler>();
```

will not create an instance of `ConfigureHandler`. It's only created when its required for the very first time. But such approaches are dangerous, as you never know if something will execute before or after it and very hard to track/debug it. Just use the DI as described in the first half of the answer and you'll be fine (and have less code to maintain or debug hard to find errors like the one you have now).

Comment: One of the reasons I ended up using a static class there is because I have a DBContext in another library, and I give the DbContext the connection string in the OnConfiguring() method. Is there a way in .net core to inject a dependency through a method instead of through the constructor?

Comment: Use the default means to configure DbContext, namely via `DbContextOptions<TContext>` and register the context using `.AddDbContext<TContext>` methods in your app. See [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions)